# StringBuilder instance being modified across several sub-classes

Tags: java

**I am trying to understand the output of the below Java code:**

```
public class BasePage
{

    private final StringBuilder str;

    public BasePage(StringBuilder str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

    protected StringBuilder getStr()
    {
        return str;
    }
}

public class HomePage extends BasePage
{
    public HomePage(StringBuilder str)
    {
        super(str);     
    }
    
    public void navigateTo()
    {
        getStr().append("Sawant");
    }
}

public class LoginPage extends BasePage
{

    public LoginPage(StringBuilder str)
    {
        super(str); 
    }

}

public class LoginPage extends BasePage
{

    public LoginPage(StringBuilder str)
    {
        super(str); 
    }

    public HomePage login()
    {
        
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(getStr());
        
        System.out.println("LoginPage value of str: " + getStr());
        System.out.println("HomePage value of str: " + homePage.getStr());
        if(getStr().toString().equals(homePage.getStr().toString()))
            System.out.println("Equals");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
        
        homePage.navigateTo();

        System.out.println("LoginPage value of str: " + getStr());
        System.out.println("HomePage value of str: " + homePage.getStr());
        if(getStr().toString().equals(homePage.getStr().toString()))
            System.out.println("Equals");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
        
        return new HomePage(getStr());
        
    }
    
}

public class TestClass
{
    private StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Sandesh");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(new TestClass().str);
        loginPage.login();
        
    }

}
```

**Output of the above code:**

```
LoginPage value of str: Sandesh
HomePage value of str: Sandesh
Equals
LoginPage value of str: SandeshSawant
HomePage value of str: SandeshSawant
Equals
```

As per my understanding, each object of the subclass maintains it's own value of the private instance variable belonging to it's superclass. Then why did the value of `str` of loginPage object changed to "SandeshSawant" when I changed only the value of `str` of homePage object by calling the navigateTo method of the HomePageClass.

But if move the entire code of the login method to the TestClass main method, then the `str` value of the loginPage object did not change.

Appreciated your help on improving my understanding on this.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger and set breakpoints in the main method and step through line by line?

Comment: Because they both point to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're carrying around the same *reference* of a StringBuilder which all modify the same string buffer.

Try returning the actual string instance

```
protected String getStr()
{
    return str.toString();
}
```

And change navigate method to use the field directly

```
public void navigateTo()
{
    super.str.append("Sawant");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. But my question is even if I use StringBuilder class and if I move the entire code of the login method to the TestClass, then the str value of the loginPage object did not change. I want to know why ?

Comment: What do you mean "entire code"? If you create `new StringBuilder()` inside the test method, and never pass it as a parameter to other places, then there is still only one reference to it. Sounds like you are not "moving code" correctly